# Problem of Wide-Table Draw by "Lyx" Program

Tags: tables, lyx

I tried to draw a table in LyX, but only half of the table appeared after the compilation. Is there is any way to customize the table size without affecting its layout?

[image]

% Preview source code for paragraph 0

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 & names & (Shakkottai et al., 2003) (Hossain et al., 2009) & Sarkar, and Narayan, 2010) & (Joshi et al., 2015a) & (Basak, and Acharya, 2015) & (Kliks et al., 2015) (Damljanovi\'{c}, 2010) (Zhang, and Zhang, 2008).  & (Cormio, and Chowdhury, 2009) & (Gogineni et al., 2012) (Ding et al., 2010)  & (Shu et al., 2014) (Liu, and Zhou, 2009)  & (Xiao, and Hu, 2008) (Xiang et al., 2010)  & (Marinho, and Monteiro, 2012) (Liu, and Zhou, 2009)  & (Mauri et al., 2014) (Youssef et al., 2014)  & (Chen et al., 2010) & (Chen, and Wyglinski, 2009) & (Bian et al., 2014) Marinho, and Monteiro, 2012 \tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
\multirow{5}{*}{} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\multirow{8}{*}{} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\multirow{5}{*}{} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-16} 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't know Lyx, but the code in the background should be with `tabularx`.

Comment: @Bernard LyX has no interface to `tabularx`. Qusay: Go into the table settings and set an explicit width for each column, that will allow linebreaking.

Answer (score 3):

You have to right click a cell in the column of which you want to change the width, it appears a pop-up, you have to choose `Settings` and in the `Table settings` you have to set the width of the column you like.

P.S. = I'm not sure about the names of the options, since I have the Italian version:

[image]

Your table is really too big, even if you put it sideways, I think it's better to divide it into two or more tables.

To have a starting point, cut and paste this MWE in any editor you want, save it as `something.lyx`, and open it in LyX (I've also added some checkmark types, available in LyX, which you can use):

```
 #LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble

\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Float table
placement H
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
What they say about a topic
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
scriptsize
\backslash
centering
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="15" columns="5">
<features booktabs="true" tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top">
<column alignment="center" valignment="middle" width="5em">
<column alignment="center" valignment="middle" width="5em">
<column alignment="center" valignment="middle" width="5em">
<column alignment="center" valignment="middle" width="5em">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Ref.
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Something
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Something
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Something
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Something else
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="2" columns="1">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="@{}c@{}">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Shakkottai et al., 2003)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Hossain et al., 2009)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✓
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✔
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✕
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✖
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Sarkar, and Narayan, 2010)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✗
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✓
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✔
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✕
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Joshi et al., 2015a)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✖
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✗
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✓
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✔
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Basak, and Acharya, 2015)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✕
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✖
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✗
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✓
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="3" columns="1">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="@{}c@{}">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Kliks et al., 2015)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Damljanović, 2010)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Zhang, and Zhang, 2008)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✔
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✕
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✖
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✗
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Cormio, and Chowdhury, 2009)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✓
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✔
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✕
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✖
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="2" columns="1">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="@{}c@{}">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Gogineni et al., 2012)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Ding et al., 2010)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✓
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✔
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="2" columns="1">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="@{}c@{}">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Shu et al., 2014)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Liu, and Zhou, 2009)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✓
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="2" columns="1">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="@{}c@{}">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Xiao, and Hu, 2008)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Xiang et al., 2010)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✓
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="2" columns="1">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="@{}c@{}">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Marinho, and Monteiro, 2012)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Liu, and Zhou, 2009)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✓
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="2" columns="1">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="@{}c@{}">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Mauri et al., 2014)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Youssef et al., 2014)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✔
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Chen et al., 2010)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✔
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Chen, and Wyglinski, 2009)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✔
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="2" columns="1">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="@{}c@{}">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Bian et al., 2014)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
(Marinho, and Monteiro, 2012)
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
✗
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

You'll get this result:

[image]

The corresponding LaTeX code is this one:

```
%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bbding}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{What they say about a topic}
\scriptsize\centering

\begin{tabular}{c>{\centering}m{5em}>{\centering}m{5em}>{\centering}m{5em}>{\centering}m{5em}}
\toprule 
Ref. & Something & Something & Something & Something else\tabularnewline
\midrule
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
(Shakkottai et al., 2003)\tabularnewline
(Hossain et al., 2009)\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} & \Checkmark{} & \CheckmarkBold{} & \XSolid{} & \XSolidBold{}\tabularnewline
\midrule 
(Sarkar, and Narayan, 2010) & \XSolidBrush{} & \Checkmark{} & \CheckmarkBold{} & \XSolid{}\tabularnewline
\midrule 
(Joshi et al., 2015a) & \XSolidBold{} & \XSolidBrush{} & \Checkmark{} & \CheckmarkBold{}\tabularnewline
\midrule 
(Basak, and Acharya, 2015) & \XSolid{} & \XSolidBold{} & \XSolidBrush{} & \Checkmark{}\tabularnewline
\midrule 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
(Kliks et al., 2015)\tabularnewline
(Damljanovi\'{c}, 2010)\tabularnewline
(Zhang, and Zhang, 2008)\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} & \CheckmarkBold{} & \XSolid{} & \XSolidBold{} & \XSolidBrush{}\tabularnewline
\midrule 
(Cormio, and Chowdhury, 2009) & \Checkmark{} & \CheckmarkBold{} & \XSolid{} & \XSolidBold{}\tabularnewline
\midrule 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
(Gogineni et al., 2012)\tabularnewline
(Ding et al., 2010)\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} & \Checkmark{} &  & \CheckmarkBold{} & \tabularnewline
\midrule 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
(Shu et al., 2014)\tabularnewline
(Liu, and Zhou, 2009)\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} &  & \Checkmark{} &  & \tabularnewline
\midrule 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
(Xiao, and Hu, 2008)\tabularnewline
(Xiang et al., 2010)\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} &  &  & \Checkmark{} & \tabularnewline
\midrule 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
(Marinho, and Monteiro, 2012)\tabularnewline
(Liu, and Zhou, 2009)\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} &  &  &  & \Checkmark{}\tabularnewline
\midrule 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
(Mauri et al., 2014)\tabularnewline
(Youssef et al., 2014)\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} &  &  & \CheckmarkBold{} & \tabularnewline
\midrule 
(Chen et al., 2010) &  & \CheckmarkBold{} &  & \tabularnewline
\midrule 
(Chen, and Wyglinski, 2009) & \CheckmarkBold{} &  &  & \tabularnewline
\midrule 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
(Bian et al., 2014)\tabularnewline
(Marinho, and Monteiro, 2012)\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} &  & \XSolidBrush{} &  & \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If you like, you can put it sideways and add more columns.

Comment: I tried to do the same steps .....and I reduce the cell size and reduce the font of the table .....but it is still not all the parts of the table appear... My table size is 15*13.

Comment: @Qusay probably your table is too big and needs to be put sideways. Make a little `.lyx` file which reproduces your problem, open it with any editor you have, and then cut and paste it in your question, please!

Comment: This is the code....There is any way to reduce the size...through a change in the code.

Comment: @Qusay Your table is really very big, what do you have to put in the empty cells? Only something brief like "yes/no" or a tick, or something long like a sentence?

Comment: Thanks For your answer....under the Authors Names...I want to add a just symbol like "x"... So, Maybe I have to change the design the table. There is any advice from you.

Comment: You're welcome! It's better if you swap rows and columns. I'll add an example tonight, if you need it...

Comment: I appreciate any suggestions or help. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Qusay See my renewed answer and let me know if you need something else :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and time....really....I benefit from the code and design...Thanks again....I will try to complete it...and If there is something sure I will tell you.  My Best Regards.

Comment: @Qusay If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). This assigns reputation points to me (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @Qusay To accept the answer you have to click the checkmark ✓, see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852. Please do it also for your other question!